# How to deal with rude new contributors?

Tags: discussion, new-users, etiquette, rude-or-abusive

I got a notification of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57760760/783743) on one of my questions. The author is a new contributor. The answer itself should have been a comment on the accepted answer. Indeed, the author had posted another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57758344/783743) before and it was promptly deleted by a moderator.

Hence, I flagged the answer for moderator attention and wrote a polite comment to inform the author on how to use Stack Overflow. I also figured out that the author was answering my question because one of his [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57752949/783743) was mistakenly marked as a duplicate of mine. Thus, I reopened his question, edited and salvaged it, and even provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761261/783743) of my own to help him.

However, he responded very rudely saying that Stack Overflow is mean to new contributors, that he'll keep posting answers on my question to make everybody suffer, and even editing his question to disparage Stack Overflow and its moderators.

How do I deal with such a person?

Comment: Responded very rudely? Flag and move on. Delete your kind comment and let the situation to moderators. Remember: **DO NOT FEED THE TROLLS!**

Comment: Flag, walk away

Comment: I'm yet again very disappointed that mods a too afraid to ban users.Some keeps posting the same answer, says that they will keep posting that answer let SO "suffer", is rude to other people and says that "stuck overflow" sucks. What else do they need to do to get banned?

Comment: @Tom, if it's their first offence, banning would be an overreaction. First, talking to the user. After that, suspension if they come back and keep at it. Then a longer suspension if they continue down that road. And so on.

Comment: @Tom When I get that feeling, I try to remember myself that I'm not a moderator, and therefore I do not know whether they were given a warning for their rude behaviour. Suspensions usually only happen when they keep causing trouble.

Comment: @yivi I actually meant suspension but forgot that word ^^. And regarding "first talk, then suspend": If I were a mod, I would do both in such cases like this here.

Comment: well @yivi in this case ... I'm not so sure I agree. I read one of their comments as an indirect threat to one of our other users. That doesn't need a gentle touch IMO.

Comment: I don’t know @rene. You are probably right, but I’m not for going to investigate this user’s actions in any case. That’s up to the mods. The general course of action I mentioned I believe it’s sound. The specifics should be decided case by case by our mighty exception handlers.

Comment: @yivi correct and agree. I raised a new flag with my concern. I move on.

Comment: You could temporarily protect your own question if a new contributor repeatedly posts non-answers.

Comment: We handled this long before your first comment, @Tom. In fact, *two* of us did, in slow succession, just to make doubly sure. Trust us when we say first warnings work. And even if it doesn't this time around (which I agree is significantly likely given this type of character), I don't expect this person to follow through with their threats before they get thrown out.

Comment: You did a great job salvaging the original question. Thanks.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes I saw that two mods deleted his "answers" already, but that, and stuff you may did in the background, didn't stop him from keep doing bad stuff, as you can see in the revision of his question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57752949/revisions where another mod had to step in. And I'm still surprised that his account is still not suspended. But I won't invest more time in this. I'm not a mod, you guys are and I'm sure you know better than me how to handle such situations/individuals.

Comment: @Tom: Oh, alright then. 3 hours ago, while I wasn't looking? *I'm* exasperated the third moderator didn't then suspend them. Consider it done.

Comment: @BoltClock You may wasn't looking, but other mods were, so no worries I don't blame you.